# Fully dynamic CoreData models in XCode

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Typical applications use XCcode's model editor to define entities and their properties.

Suppose, I'd like to create an application, which needs more flexibility. The app needs to create fresh **new entity-types with arbitrary attributes**.

**May a Cocoa application create new entity-tpes at run-time?**

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers, you should post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating or copying and modifying an NSManagedObjectModel, the documentation for this class is a good place to start. There are some caveats, though, you can't just modify it on the fly as it invalidates your persistent store - so you'd have to do a migration to a new persistent store based on your new model.